# JavaScript background work (wait until all processing finished and display result )

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, background-process

i'm working in an application

i have to change some css files in the page and some images (reloading them from the server) using javascript , but it takes some time and it's obvious that page items are reloaded slowly -in slow connections-  , so is it possible to do this processing in the background and then display the whole page when ready ??

Comment: what kind of processing do you mean, and how are you exactly using javascript to retrieve your data?

Comment: @alexanderb  : i'm just changing some elements in the DOM to load new css files and images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU you can put it in a hidden IFRAME. In this IFRAME you handle onLoad event. However, this won't fasten up loading process, it will only hide it from user.

Examle:
Let's say that you have a long-lasting JavaScript method named longLoad() . You should put it in a separate HTML page named e.g. **hidden.html**.

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function longLoad() // javascript method here...
   {
     /// some code here...
   }
  </script>
  <body onLoad="longLoad();">
  </body>  
</html>
```

Your main page (the one that is actually visible in browser) may look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
....
.... content
....
<iframe src ="hidden.html" width="100%" height="0">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see IFRAME height is set to 0 making it invisible on the page- that's why I called it *hidden*. However, when the user loads the page, the hidden IFRAME will be loaded too. And its onLoad event handler will also be called. And it is possible to **access and modify** content of the main page from that JavaScript event handler (through DOM trees).

PS. The above code was written from memory, however the presented solution works. It was used long before AJAX came into popularity.

Comment: could you explain more please

Answer (score 1):

You can *hide* the whole page while your work is going on, or you could load your CSS and images and only do the updates to the DOM when all your materials have made it to the client.

You can load an image by creating a new Image object:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { /* do something */ };
img.src = "/new/image.png";
```

The "onload" function will run when the client has received the image file and it's ready to be displayed. Thus you could arrange to load up images that way, and use the "load" handlers to track when they're ready. When all of them are, then you can update the DOM and it should go very quickly.

Comment: Generally I wouldn't recommend this for all images. If one image can't be loaded (connection lost or something similar) the whole page won't be displayed. I'd restrict this to the most important ones.

Comment: @acme yes that's good advice, though for an established site it should generally be the case that things like that are available.

Comment: @pointy thnx for ur answer , but hiding the whole page isn't available in my case due to some business requirements

Comment: @mahmoud then in that case I'd do the trick with loading images via Image objects as I described. That will allow the browsers to cache the images, so that when you update the DOM the images will be ready.